# Como faço para traçar o gráfico da função de produção de Cobb-Douglas no R?

Tags: r

Gostaria de elaborar o gráfico para a função de produção de Cobb-Douglas no R,um exemplo seria a função:

P(L, K) = 1,01L^0,75 k^0,25

Onde  L e K variam entre 0 e 300.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta resposta necessita do pacote `plot3D` instalado. Se ainda não o tiver instalado, pode fazê-lo com

```
install.packages("plot3D")
```

Primeiro defino uma função `cobbDouglas` bastante geral, que também aceita como argumentos a constante `A` e os expoentes `alpha` e `beta`.

```
cobbDouglas <- function(K, L, A, alpha, beta){
  A * L^beta * K^alpha
}
```

Agora é primeiro calcular os valores da função, com `outer()`.

```
L <- 0:300
K <- 0:300
Z <- outer(K, L, cobbDouglas, A = 1.01, alpha = 0.25, beta = 0.75)
```

E traçar o gráfico com `plot3D::persp3D`. Antes disso redefino os valores das margens para ter mais espaço para o gráfico e no fim repõem-se os parâmetros gráficos tal como estavam.

```
op <- par(bg = "white", mar = c(1, 1, 1, 2) + 0.1)
plot3D::persp3D(L, K, Z, theta = 30, phi = 30, 
                expand = 0.5, col = rainbow(100))
par(op)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Perfeito,obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Aqui vai uma das infinitas possibilidades para realizar o que você deseja:

```
# criar uma função
P = function(L, K) {
  return(1.01 * L^0.75 * K^0.25 )
}

# Variáveis
L = K = 0:300

# definir amostra de uma variável para plotar em função da outra
amostra <- seq(0, 300, 20)

# definir cores
cols <- rainbow(length(amostra))

# 2 plots
par(mfrow = c(1, 2), mar = c(3,3,0.5,0.5), mgp = c(1.5, 0.3, 0), tck = -.008)

# L
plot(0, pch = '', xlim = c(0, 300), ylim = c(0, 200), xlab = 'L', ylab = 'F(L, K)')
for(k in 1:length(amostra)) {
  points(L, P(L, K[k]), type = 'l', col = cols[k])
}
legend('topleft', legend = amostra, title = 'K', lty = 1, col = cols, bty = 'n', cex = 0.7)

# K
plot(0, pch = '', xlim = c(0, 300), ylim = c(0, 100), xlab = 'K', ylab = 'F(L, K)')
for(l in 1:length(amostra)) {
  points(K, P(L[l], K), type = 'l', col = cols[l])
}
legend('topleft', legend = amostra, title = 'L', lty = 1, col = cols, bty = 'n', cex = 0.7)
```

Comment: Perfeito,obrigado!